Sending email from server to gmail is not working
I ran this code in bash to send email from ubuntu server
#!/bin/bash  

# Variables  
recipient="xyz@abc.com"  
subject="Subject of the email"  
body="This is the body of the email."  

# Attempt to send the email  
if echo "$body" | mail -s "$subject" "$recipient"; then  
  echo "Email sent successfully to $recipient."  
else  
  echo "Failed to send email to $recipient. Please check your mail configuration."  
fi

I was successful to send email to proton mail, although proton receive email in spam folder, but it is not working for gmail
when using tail -f /var/log/mail.log to track logs I receive this response
Dec 29 15:06:04 xxx postfix/pickup[443359]: 1FA128B02B: uid=1000 from=<azureuser@xxx.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net>
Dec 29 15:06:04 xxx postfix/cleanup[443922]: 1FA128B02B: message-id=<20241229150604.1FA128B02B@xxx.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net>
Dec 29 15:06:04 xxx postfix/qmgr[443360]: 1FA128B02B: from=<azureuser@xxx.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net>, size=526, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/smtp[443924]: 1FA128B02B: to=<YYY@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.2.27]:25, delay=0.89, delays=0.02/0.01/0.46/0.39, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.2.27] said: 550-5.7.26 Your email has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated. 550-5.7.26 Gmail requires all senders to authenticate with either SPF or DKIM. 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  Authentication results: 550-5.7.26  DKIM = did not pass 550-5.7.26  SPF [openvpn.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net] 550-5.7.26 with ip: [20.163.28.40] = did not pass 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  For instructions on setting up authentication, go to 550 5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication d2e1a72fcca58-72aad83ae40si25723079b3a.1 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/cleanup[443922]: 234AB8B02C: message-id=<20241229150605.234AB8B02C@openvpn.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net>
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/bounce[443925]: 1FA128B02B: sender non-delivery notification: 234AB8B02C
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/qmgr[443360]: 234AB8B02C: from=<>, size=4316, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/qmgr[443360]: 1FA128B02B: removed
Dec 29 15:06:05 xxx postfix/local[443928]: 234AB8B02C: to=<azureuser@xxx.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Dec 29 15:06:05 openvpn postfix/qmgr[443360]: 234AB8B02C: removed

is it necessary to setting up SPF or DKIM?

From your mail.log: "Your email has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated. 550-5.7.26 Gmail requires all senders to authenticate with either SPF or DKIM. 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  Authentication results: 550-5.7.26  DKIM = did not pass 550-5.7.26  SPF [openvpn.msh1giz1qitexf4gtqk2kxjeud.phxx.internal.cloudapp.net] 550-5.7.26 with ip: [20.163.28.40] = did not pass 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  For instructions on setting up authentication, go to 550 5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication d2e1a72fcca58-72aad83ae40si25723079b3a.1 - gsmtp"

If your email is on a cloudfront or VPN server it's unlikely to ever authenticate for your domain. Since the recent changes to security. GMail enforces DMARC, which means you need SPF records and DKIM records on your email being sent by your mail server AND being at a proper destination with matching forward and reverse DNS records on the sender IP address to the hostname your server identifies as. ProtonMail marks your item as spam. GMail outright denies because they have harder enforcement due to their policies.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096574

FYI I could go on an hour long lecture about the chaos of maintaining everything yourself, but I won't. I could also go on a two hour long lecture about how to set up a mail server that you can send through that would successfully pass SPF, DKIM, and DMARC requirements to pass most mail servers' restrictions simply for sending mail as a domain, but that's an answer too long to fit here with all the proper security precautions, steps, etc.

@petep That's for sending as a GMail account.  Not for sending mail from another mail server to a GMail recipient.

"is it necessary to setting up SPF or DKIM?" Yes, but you also need to use a fully formed mail command that includes the sender as well so it sends as an actual user with a FROM header instead of a random azureuser@long-azure-domain-you-don't-control URL string like it is currently.
